# Pyinstaller Error after exe built: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath'

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I'm having a hard time converting my python code to an exe. After I use pyinstaller to convert my code to an exe, it gives me an error that its missing an import when I run it. Here's the full log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "nsepython/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "nsepython/rahu.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pandas/__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pandas/testing.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pandas/_testing.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/testing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.testing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmath'
[74486] Failed to execute script new
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

The name of the file I'm trying to convert is new.py which relies on pandas which apparently can't find a module called cmath. How do I fix this? Is there anyway for me to build an exe?

Comment: `cmath` is a Python standard library module that des complex arithmetic. So it is always available. It may be that `pyinstaller` can't figure out that it is needed, and so has not included it in the `.exe`. Look in the `pyinstaller` docs to find out how you hint in the `.spec` file that it should be included.

Comment: Ah yes I figured it out, you're right @BoarGules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `--hidden-import cmath` to the pyinstaller run.

Comment: it says : NameError: name 'cmath' is not defined

Comment: Looks like the hook for Pandas was updated to include this import: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/5630